# Android Storage Access Framework - start picker for custom file type

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I am trying to use the SAF picker in my application to look for my custom file types. Doing this is easy enough when the file has a mime type by calling setType("text/plain") or similar.

What would the call look like if I wanted to look for, say, all files with the '.blah' extension?

**Edit**: more information: the file type is actually a plain text file with a changed extension. In the file, some text exists which I parse to create some data structure from it. However, when the user looks for the file of the specific extension, I would like them to see only my custom files, not all text files.

Comment: I've the same question. Did you solved it?

Comment: @SergioViudes: no, I just learned to live with it the way it is.

Comment: @wujek Have you solved the issus?

Comment: No sorry, I've moved on and never really took care of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a 100 percent sure if this also applies to android (cause I have not used it until now), but in general the mimetype for all binary files can be 'application/octet-stream' if you don't know what type of file you are dealing with